# Express cookies don't work on Netlify deployment, although they work fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, deployment

I'm trying to deploy the frontend part of my react-nodejs messenger app on netlify,
but the cookies are not being set on my netlify frontend, although they work normally on my localhost frontend.
and hence, I can't access express session or authenticate users..

(Please note that the server is still on my localhost)

I'm using cors library,
and I have set the origin to my netlify app domain, and credentials to true..

and here's my session & cookie settings:

```
 session({
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  credentials:true,
  name:"sid",
  store: new RedisStore({ client:redisClient }),
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false,
  cookie:{
    secure:false,
    httpOnly:true,
    sameSite:"lax",
    expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 
  }

})
```

and here's the repo: [Github Repo](https://github.com/SaifAshrafHelmy/BuzzChat/tree/prod)